# Why doesn't this work to connect my database?

Tags: php, mysql5

What did I do wrong with this code ?

```
 $query = "SELECT name, emailadres FROM people";
 //query is aangemaakt
 $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
 //query is uitgevoerd
```

and is this working

```
 $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT name, emailadres FROM people") or die (mysqli_error());
 //query is uitgevoerd
```

Comment: Have you tried quoting the `query` variable?, as `$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "$query")`

Comment: It gives only the choice: '.$record['naam'].'

Comment: Already checked logs? Try setting `die()` to let it tell you what does the database say.

Comment: your code looks fine to me. What error you are getting?

Comment: @All: The problem was found in a too early placed "?>". So it looks like  the database could'nt not readable.